# How to get Chirpy working with JS and mash.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, compression, minify, chirpy

I just downloaded and installed the most recent version of Chirpy [[Nude Chirpy v1.0.0.5.3](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)]
I created a "mash.less.chirp.config" file in my CSS directory, and it's compressing/minifying very spectacularly!!!

```
<root>
    <FileGroup Name="site.css">
        <File Path="elements.css" />
        <File Path="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" />
        <File Path="site.less" />
        <File Path="wmd.css" />
    </FileGroup>
</root>
```

I also created a "mash.chirp.config" file in my Script directory, unfortunately it's not doing anything at all.

```
<root>
    <FileGroup Name="site.js">
        <File path="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" Minify="false" />
        <File path="un-master.js" />
        <File path="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js" Minify="false" />
        <File path="jquery-nmcFormHelper.js" />
        <File path="jquery.textarearesizer.min.js" Minify="false" />
        <File path="jquery-openid.js" />
        <File path="jquery.timeago.js" />
    </FileGroup>
</root>
```

any help/direction on this will be greatly appreciated.

**[ADDED INFO]**

1. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional
2. I've got an ASP.NET MVC3 Project

Folder Structure...

> ROOT/Assets/Scripts/mash.chirp.config
>      ROOT/Assets/Scripts/[all_my_js_files].js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capitalize the p in path, brah!

Comment: You bet! Let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Next time you're on, would you mind talking a look at that question?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my config to the following, and it seems to be working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns="urn:ChirpyConfig"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ChirpyConfig http://www.weirdlover.com/chirpy/chirp.xsd">
    <FileGroup Name="site.js">
        <File Path="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" Minify="false" />
        <File Path="un-master.js" />
        <File Path="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js" Minify="false" />
        <File Path="jquery-nmcFormHelper.js" />
        <File Path="jquery.textarearesizer.min.js" Minify="false" />
        <File Path="jquery-openid.js" />
        <File Path="jquery.timeago.js" />
    </FileGroup>
</root>
```

Evidently it's case sensitive **P**ath instead of **p**ath.